# General Graph Cycle Detection (Confirm my Answer please)

Tags: graph, cycle, depth-first-search

The problem:

An undirected graph is unicyclic if it contains exactly one cycle. Describe an O( |V| + |E| ) algorithm for determining whether or not a given graph, G is unicyclic.

My solution:

int i = 0

Run a modified DFS on G, where we increment i everytime we decide not to visit a vertex because it has already been visited.

After DFS is done, if i==1, graph is unicyclic.

I thought this solution would work but am wondering if there is a counter example that would prove it false. If anyone could clarify that would be great, Thanks.

Comment: "where we increment i everytime we decide not to visit a vertex because it has already been visited." what do you mean by this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your graph consists of a single connected component?

In this case just count vertices and edges and check |V| - |E| = 0

Otherwise count the number of connected components O(|V| + |E|), 
and check |V| - |E| = number of connected components - 1.

*Remark:* having more than one connected component is a counterexample to your algorithm.

Comment: Oh that is clever, but would it not be check |V| - |E| = 0, since a graph containing 2 vertices and 1 edge is not a cyclce and 2-1=1. Also, would my algorithm would work if I restarted the modified DFS in each component?

Comment: @user2931097 thanks for the remark, I've just edited

Answer (score 0):

```
"Increment i everytime we decide not to visit a vertex because 
it has already been visited."
```

I am quite unclear about what you are trying to do here.

Rather then this, how about this:

Perform DFS and count number of back edges.

```
A back edge is an edge that is from a node to itself (selfloop) or one of its 
ancestor in the tree produced by DFS.
```

If number of back edges ==1 then unicycle else not.

```
To count number of back edges, follow this algorithm.

To detect a back edge, we can keep track of vertices currently in recursion stack of 
function for DFS traversal. If we reach a vertex that is already in the recursion stack,
then there is a cycle in the tree. The edge that connects current vertex to the
vertex in the recursion stack is back edge
```

Comment: I meant that I would modify the portion of the DFS code to be if vertex v is unexplored then label e as a discovered edge, recursively call DFS(G,v) ELSE i++ (increment i because we decided not to visit an already visited node)